# Return a Model that Doesn't Exist Yet For Tastypie to Use

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a model with a number of settings:

```
class SettingsProfile(models.Model):

  video_enabled = BooleanField()
  audio_enabled = BooleanField()
  sensors_enabled = BooleanField()
  reporting Enabled = BooleanField()
```

If a user has already created a SettingsProfile model, things are fine, we can query the /v1/settingsprofiles/ endpoint and get what we need.

However, if a settings profile does not exist that matches my query (the given user hasn't created it yet), I want to return a SettingsProfile resource with some default settings filled out. Note that I don't want to CREATE a SettingsProfile row in the DB, I just want to display what LOOKS like a SettingsProfile resource but is really just displaying some defaults.

Is there some kind of way to coax Django into creating what looks like a model but hasn't been saved to the DB and getting Tastypie to use that to supply the client when they make a GET request for a SettingsProfile that does not yet exist?

Comment: Untill you call save() on Django model it does not get save in db but the object is created in memory which can be used to set the default data and also can be passed to different functions. Another option to pass `commit=False` to `SettingsProfile.save(commit=False)` function this will create object with default values without commiting to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SettingsProfile(models.Model):
    video_enabled = BooleanField(default=True)
    audio_enabled = BooleanField(default=False)
    sensors_enabled = BooleanField(default=True)
    reporting_enabled = BooleanField(default=False)
```

.

```
try:
    settings_profile = SettingsProfile.objects.get(user=user)
except SettingsProfile.DoesNotExist:
    settings_profile = SettingsProfile()  # A new one with default values
```